# Count and display multiple mysql row values in different columns for PHP echo

Tags: php, mysql, count, group-by, echo

I have using following mysql statement to count and retrieve multiple database rows in mysql database:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leavesrecords WHERE leavetype IN ('Casual','Annual','Medical') and empno = '202'  GROUP BY leavetype
```

But the output of this query only contain one column and the column name is  `COUNT(*)`. This query returns three counted values and I want those value to assign PHP variables. following PHP code I used to get values:

```
include 'database.php';
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leavesrecords WHERE leavetype IN ('Casual','Annual','Medical') and empno = '202'  GROUP BY leavetype; ";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

$num = $stmt->rowCount();
if($num>0){
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        extract($row);
        echo $row["leavesrecords"];
    } 
}
else{ echo "";}
?>
```

But this code throwing me an error without showing single value. I want to assign those three mysql counts to three mysql variables. how can I do that?

Comment: Have a look at a tutorial or 2 https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using an `IF` or `CASE` statement in your query to return a single row:

```
 SELECT sum(if(leavetype='Casual',1,0)) AS `CasualCount`,
    sum(if(leavetype='Annual',1,0)) AS `AnnualCount`,
    sum(if(leavetype='Medical',1,0)) as `MedicalCount`
FROM leaverecords
WHERE leavetype IN ('Casual','Annual','Medical') and empno = '202';
```

Now you will have 1 row with three fields.

Comment: This add three columns to the result but only column one is populated other two columns not populated

Comment: MySQL... The day I understand its idiosyncracies... I've updated to use `sum(if())` Hopefully that does the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but after update it giving error ant not counting values !!

Comment: Ok I manged to fix your query and now it working perfectly fine !! SELECT sum(if(leavetype='Casual',1,0)) as `CasualCount`,
    sum(if(leavetype='Annual',1,0)) as `AnnualCount`,
    sum(if(leavetype='Medical',1,0)) as `MedicalCount`
FROM leavesrecords
WHERE leavetype IN ('Casual','Annual','Medical') and empno = '202';

Comment: Yea... I was just going through and correcting the syntax and fieldname errors. It was riddled with them. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

You should use  an alias for thr column result

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) as my_count 
 FROM leavesrecords 
 WHERE leavetype IN ('Casual','Annual','Medical') and empno = '202'  GROUP BY leavetype
```

and  refer to the column using the alias name for key

```
if($num>0){
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        // extract($row);
        echo $row["my_count"];
    } 
}
```

You should not refer to the rows contens using the tablename but a proper column name